# Get picked image on Android with React Native Fetch API

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

I'm using React Native and Expo.  I'm using the Expo image picker which returns a local URI to an image file.  The URI returned looks like this:
`file:///data/user/0/com.myapp/cache/ExperienceData/%2540myapp%252Fmyapp/ImagePicker/c5a29113-7c8f-4224-99ec-007f641841ee.jpg`

On iOS, I can use the [React Native Fetch API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network) to get the blob so I can upload it to S3 using the [Amplify Storage Service](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#put).  Everything works fine.

On Android, however, it does not work.  The fetch command returns `1` rather than a response; there are no errors.

I can't use (well, don't want to use) rn-fetch-blob because my application is detached and the rn-fetch-blob needs to be patched to work with Expo 32.

Funny thing though ... if instead of using the image resizer's URI, I use an image URL from the network, it works on both Android and iOS.  So, how do I use fetch on Android to return the contents of the local file from the Android image picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my searching for a solution to this problem, I ran across [this post](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2402#issuecomment-443726662).  The explanation is pretty thorough.  Here's the TL;DR . . .

As of RN 0.57, the polyfill they use for fetch doesn't default the xhr.responseType to `blob` anymore.  The [React Native for Android BlobModule](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/4148976a83ab96029de1b26b515ff95d3cb58c10/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/blob/BlobModule.java#L80-L85) checks the response type to determine if it can handle the URL when it's not an http or https request.  Since the responseType is never `'blob'`, this module never handles the request, and a type error is thrown . . . on android . . . for file requests . . . through the [whatwg-fetch.js polyfill](https://github.com/expo/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/vendor/core/whatwg-fetch.js#L10-L12) . . . for RN 0.57+.

Based on the aforementioned post on the expo issue, I added this as a (hopefully) temporary solution.

```
requestBlob = (uri) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.response);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });
}
```

I'm saving my image like this:

```
  let body, storedImage;
  try {
    body = await requestBlob(localImageUri).catch(error => errors.push(error));
    storedImage = await Storage.put(path, body).catch(error => errors.push(error));
  } finally {
    body.close();
  }
```

Comment: This worked as a charm for react-native 0.72.x, thanks.

issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38625